# CakePHP - Getting data from deep relationships?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

My relationships are as follows:

```
User hasMany Item, Offer, Watcher

Item BelongsTo User
Item hasMany Offer, Watcher

Offer/Watcher BelongTo Item & User
```

When I try to get the Users Items using this:

```
    $this->loadModel( 'User', $this->Auth->user( 'id' ) );
    $this->set( 'user', $this->User->read() );
```

It gets the users record, the items they're watching and items they've made offers on which is fine.

However on the users items that they're selling it wont get the watchers/offers correctly.

if I use: `$this->User->recursive = 2;` Then it only gets the user_id but doesn't associate it to the users profile at all!

Example:

http://pastebin.com/9A8k7rDs

I can get this information by including the models individually and getting the data that way, but that's such a hack.

I was wondering if anyone knew any better ways?! or even if my relationships are right :z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I used `$this->User->Item->find( ... )` with `$this->Item->recursive = 2;`

It returned the data I wanted and a bit extra so I controlled that with the containable behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Found out I didn't need the recursive as 2. Containable behaviour does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the relationships set up in all the models? Meaning not only do you have to have the relationship in the User model, but also in the Item, Watcher and Offer models as well.

Comment: Yep. In every model there's a hasMany and belongsTo.